# How to write Postgres JSONB Where clausule

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have the following Table:

```
CREATE TABLE mbiz.dictionary_groups (
    slgr_id jsonb NOT NULL,
    stored jsonb NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT dictionary_groups_pkey PRIMARY KEY (slgr_id)
);
```

and keeps json object in column called 'stored', example:

```
{
    "Position": 
        {"RotationId": 0, "SubGroupId": 0, "DiscoutGroupId": 99, "PriceIntervalId": 0},
    "DefaultValue": 0.0, 
    "PositionValues": 
    [
        {"Value": 26.0, "ProfileId": 1}, 
        {"Value": 18.0, "ProfileId": 2}, 
        {"Value": 33.0, "ProfileId": 12}
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to find all records where any record in 'PositionValues' will have 'ProfileId' equal to 2.

It's a Postgres 9.5, I found some tips where users suggest to use `?` or `@>` but when I tried it, I received error message:

> "SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: @> unknown
>    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
>     Position: 85"

Comment: Please also post your query.

Comment: This query is not working:

SELECT * FROM dictionary_groups sgr WHERE sgr.stored -> 'PositionValues' -> 'ProfileId' = '2' ;

Probably there is a need to use ANY or something similar

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using a JSONB column as the primary key seems rather strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an array on the right hand side:

```
select *
from dictionary_groups
where "stored" -> 'PositionValues' @> '[{"ProfileId": 2}]';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a84b9ae5ab97c817dcf15a93272e7f2e)